If $\mathbf{A}^{m\times n}$, $m>n$, is full rank, then $\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}$ is positive definite
I remember reading this somewhere, but I can't find it nor prove. Two questions:

Is the sentence right?
Does anyone know where I can find the proof?

Thanks

What did you try? Hint: Can you find $v\in\mathbb R^n$, $v\neq 0$ such that $Av = 0$?

Matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is full rank, so their kernel only contains $\mathbf{v}=0$

That is right. And what is the definition of positive definite?

@jgpallero Yes, the sentence is correct.

I'll try to answer myself:
$\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}$ will be positive definite if $\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{Av}>0, \forall\mathbf{v}\neq0$. As $\mathbf{A}$ is of full rank, $\mathbf{Av}\neq0, \forall\mathbf{v}\neq0$, so, being $\mathbf{Av}=\mathbf{b}$, then $\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{Av}=\mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{b}$, which is a sum of squares, so $\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{Av}>0, \forall\mathbf{v}\neq0$ and $\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}$ is positive definite
